# Simple.Data - Primary Key Mapping

Tags: simple.data

i'm using Simple.Data and I have a question about.

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Admin : User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}
```

And a class that makes the actions in database:

```
public class Manager
{
    public string ConString { get; set; }

    public Manager()
    {
        ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
    }


    public void CustomerUpdate()
    {       
        var obj = new Customer()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Username = "teste",
            Password = "teste",
            Salt = "",
            Email = "teste@teste.com"
        };

        var db = Database.OpenConnection(conString);
        db.tbCustomer.Update(obj);
    }
    public void AdminUpdate()
    {           
        var obj = new Admin()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Username = "teste",
            Password = "teste",
            Salt = "",
            Name = "teste",
            IsActive = true             
        };

        var db = Database.OpenConnection(conString);
        db.tbAdmin.Update(obj);
    }
}
```

But, i have a problem:

In my db, in the table tbCustomer, the Primary Key is the "CustomerId" column. And the Primary Key of the table tbAdmin is the "AdminId" column.
As the User class has a property called "Id", I can not do updates.

Is there any way I map for when you're giving update on tbCustomer table, the system take "Id" property and enter the "CustomerId" column?
Same for tbAdmin. I want him to take "Id" and place in "AdminId".

Answer (score 1):

If you can't rename the property in your class the best option is most likely to use [**Named Parameters**](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Modify/UpdatingData.html) in your update instead of passing the object. An example for yours would be

```
db.tbCustomer.UpdateById(Id: 1, 
                         Username: "teste",
                         ...);
```

Comment: Thank you
I was trying to get away from this method.
I managed to do otherwise. Added properties to the Customer and Admin classes and they return the Id Ex.:



public int AdminId { get { return Id; } }